# Splitting an array into multiple parts?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a 2D array I am looking for an elegant and performant way to divide up a 1D array of `words` given a start index and end index.

```
// pass this in as an arg
var trim = [
  [3, 4], // remove two words at index 3 and 4
  [9, 10] // remove two words at index 9 and 10
]; // use this to reformat

var words = [
  { word: "hello", st: 0 },
  { word: "stack-overflow", st: 0.5 },
  { word: "lets", st: 1 },
  { word: "remove", st: 1.5 },
  { word: "some", st: 2 },
  { word: "words", st: 2.5 },
  { word: "efficiently", st: 3 },
  { word: "lets", st: 3.5 },
  { word: "do", st: 4 },
  { word: "it", st: 4.5 },
  { word: "yay", st: 5 }
];

// this is the result I am looking for
var result = [
  [
    { word: "hello", st: 0 },
    { word: "stack-overflow", st: 0.5 },
    { word: "lets", st: 1 }
  ],
  [
    { word: "words", st: 2.5 },
    { word: "efficiently", st: 3 },
    { word: "lets", st: 3.5 },
    { word: "do", st: 4 }
  ]
];
```

This is the best I could do, missing return as 2D array

```
words.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
    const wordBetween = trim.some(t => {
        return t[0] <= i && t[1] >= i
    });

    console.log({wordBetween, curr})

    if (wordBetween) {
        return acc;
    }
    
    return [...acc, curr]
}, [])
```

Comment: The first step would be to make an attempt to write some code that accomplishes what you want. After that, you can refine it until it suits the standards you're looking for.

Comment: Updated original post with an attempt, failed to make 2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure elegance!  And supreme performance!  Jokes aside, this should convey the idea.

```
let start = 0;
let result = [];
for (let [end, newStart] of trim) {
  result.push(words.slice(start, end));
  start = newStart + 1;
}
result.push(words.slice(start, words.length));
```

Note that 2 splits results in three chunks ( n splits give n+1 chunks ) so there might be an empty array at the start or end.  This has precedence in string.split.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to filter an array, removing some specified indexes...

```js
const arrayWithoutIndexes = (array, indexes) => {
  return array.filter((el, i) => !indexes.includes(i));
};

var words = [
  { word: "hello", st: 0 },
  { word: "stack-overflow", st: 0.5 },
  { word: "lets", st: 1 },
  { word: "remove", st: 1.5 },
  { word: "some", st: 2 },
  { word: "words", st: 2.5 },
  { word: "efficiently", st: 3 },
  { word: "lets", st: 3.5 },
  { word: "do", st: 4 },
  { word: "it", st: 4.5 },
  { word: "yay", st: 5 }
];

console.log(arrayWithoutIndexes(words, [1,4]));
```

EDIT: To handle several sets of indexes, producing a new set of edited words for each set of indexes, just map that function over the index input...

```js
const arrayWithoutIndexes = (array, indexes) => {
  // the map here just copies the word, so the result has new word objects
  return array.filter((el, i) => !indexes.includes(i)).map(o => Object.assign({}, o));
};

var words = [
  { word: "hello", st: 0 },
  { word: "stack-overflow", st: 0.5 },
  { word: "lets", st: 1 },
  { word: "remove", st: 1.5 },
  { word: "some", st: 2 },
  { word: "words", st: 2.5 },
  { word: "efficiently", st: 3 },
  { word: "lets", st: 3.5 },
  { word: "do", st: 4 },
  { word: "it", st: 4.5 },
  { word: "yay", st: 5 }
];

let removeThese = [
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
];

let result = removeThese.map(indexes => arrayWithoutIndexes(words, indexes));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think yours is more efficient than mine, I update OP... However in both situations I am looking to get a 2D array so its split up

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry - it's a little simpler to produce an edited word lest for each index input...you do it by mapping the `arrayWithoutIndexes` function over the input array.  Edited to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

we can make uses of `JSON.stringify` to split up the objects.

```js
const splitArrayBasedOnIndexes = (arr = [], indexToRemove = []) => {
    indexToRemove = indexToRemove.flat(Infinity);
    let result = JSON.stringify(arr.map((w, i) => {
        if (indexToRemove.includes(i)) return null;
        return w
    }))
    result = result.substring(1, result.lastIndexOf("]")).split("null").reduce((p, c) => {
        if (c.substring(c.indexOf("{"), c.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))
            p.push(JSON.parse("[" + c.substring(c.indexOf("{"), c.lastIndexOf("}") + 1) + "]"))
        return p
    }, []);

    return result;
}

const words = [
    { word: "hello", st: 0 },
    { word: "stack-overflow", st: 0.5 },
    { word: "lets", st: 1 },
    { word: "remove", st: 1.5 },
    { word: "some", st: 2 },
    { word: "words", st: 2.5 },
    { word: "efficiently", st: 3 },
    { word: "lets", st: 3.5 },
    { word: "do", st: 4 },
    { word: "it", st: 4.5 },
    { word: "yay", st: 5 }
];

const trim = [
    [3, 4],
    [9, 10]
];

console.log(splitArrayBasedOnIndexes(words, trim));
```